# How to pass dynamic value in sql queries

Tags: sql, dynamic

I have a table in which there are some columns say (a,b,c,d,e) . Based on the user input i want to select the value from particular column .  For eg if user gives a then i want select a from table , similarly if user chooses  then i want select b from table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select case @InputValue
        when 'A' then ColumnA 
        when 'B' then ColumnB
        else ColumnC
    end
from MyTable
```

Comment: i framed query in a string and then exec(query)